# 'Non static variable cannot be... ' error

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to add a scrollbar to my photo viewer but the it gives me the error that a non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context.

To be exact, I'm trying to add a scrollbar to a JPanel. Also, if I make JScrollPane scrollBar a static variable, then the photo wont appear. TIA

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class PhotoViewer 
{
// Instance fields.
private FilenameFilter fileNameFilter;
private JFileChooser fileChooser;
private JMenuBar menuBar;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private static JScrollPane scrollBar;

public PhotoViewer() // Constructor.
{ 
    // Main JPanel with a grid style layout.
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

    // Jlabel to display photo on.
    final JLabel imageView = new JLabel();
    // Adds the JLabel ontop of the JPanel.
    mainPanel.add(imageView);

    // Adds a scroll bar. 
    scrollBar = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);       
    scrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);    

    // Creates a file chooser to find a photo.
    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    // Creates a new menubar at the top of the JPanel.
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    // Adds a menu within the JMenuBar.
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("View new photo");
    // Adds the additional menu ontop of the original JMenuBar.
    menuBar.add(menu);
    // Option to browse for a new photo. 
    JMenuItem browse = new JMenuItem("Browse");
    // Adds the browse option ontop of the 'View new photo' button. 
    menu.add(browse);

    // Creates an actionlistener to follow what the user is doing.
    browse.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
            {
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainPanel);
                // Displays the image if approved by JFileChooser.
                if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                {
                    // Obtains the selected file by the user.
                    File singleImage = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    try 
                    {   
                        // Displays the image if no exception.
                        Image displayImage = ImageIO.read(singleImage);
                        imageView.setIcon(new ImageIcon(displayImage));
                    } catch(Exception e)                        
                    {
                        // Displays the exception caught by the program in a JOptionPane window.
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, e, "Load failure!",   JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 

} // end of constructor PhotoViewer

public void loadImages(File directory) throws IOException 
{   
    // Throws an exception to be caught. 
    File[] imageFiles = directory.listFiles(fileNameFilter);
    BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[imageFiles.length];
} // end of method loadImages(File directory)

public Container getPanel() 
{
    // Hands execution back to the mainPanel function.
    return mainPanel;
}// end of method getPanel()

public JMenuBar getMenuBar() 
{
    // Hands execution back to the menuBar function.
    return menuBar;
}// end of method getMenuBar()

public JScrollPane getScrollBar() 
{
    // Hands execution back to the menuBar function.
    return scrollBar;
}// end of method getScrollBar()

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                // Input all the compoenents of the photo viewer to the JFrame to       display them.
                PhotoViewer imageList = new PhotoViewer();

                // Creates a new JFrame to display everything.
                JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Photo Viewer");
                // 'Throws away' the JFrame on close. 
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // Adds all the different components to the JFrame.
                mainFrame.add(imageList.getPanel());
                mainFrame.add(imageList.getScrollBar());
                mainFrame.setJMenuBar(imageList.getMenuBar());
                mainFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                // Packs all the components into the JFrame. 
                mainFrame.pack();
                // Sets the size of the JFrame.
                mainFrame.setSize(1500,1500);
                // Allows us to see the JFrame.
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
} // end of method main(String[] args)
} // end of class PhotoViewer
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace

Comment: @AliAlamiri: There are no stacktraces for compiler errors...

Comment: @jlordo but this code complies just fine.

Comment: How would I find the stack trace? Sorry I'm a noob at Java.

Comment: @jlordo What dantuch said

Comment: @dantuch: that's possible. But OP mentioned that he gets `a non static variable cannot be referenced from a static context`, which is clearly a compiler error, and not a runtime error or exception.

Comment: Sorry not to clarify. The non static error was obtained when I did not make JScrollPane a static variable. But when I do that, then the image I find from my directory will not display.

Comment: @user2205330 Your program compiles fine. You have no non-static variables in a static context. I don't know how you're getting this error.

Comment: @AliAlamiri the problem is that even though I get no error, now the photo I choose will not display, however if I remove the static from JScrollPane I end up getting that error.

Comment: @user2205330 EVEN if you remove the static keyword from the JScrollPane, you still won't get an error, as long as you don't use the field name inside main and stick to using the getter method

Comment: Changing the code *only* removing the static modifier from that variable, it still compiles and runs.

Comment: I get an error if I remove the static keyword. Strange. realized it was a problem on my part.

Comment: @user2205330 Are you using the NAME of the JScrollPane inside main when you remove the static keyword, or do you keep using the getter method for it?

Comment: @AliAlamiri that was the problem. It's fine now, the only remaining issue is that the photo I choose won't display when I have the JScrollPane added to my JPanel.

Comment: @user2205330 I think (and I'm not 100% sure) you may need a listener to your JLabel or JFrame to see if any image has been chosen and add it to the JLabel if it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to add `mainPanel` and `scrollBar` separately, as `scrollBar` already contains `mainPanel`. Just execute `mainFrame.add(imageList.getScrollBar());` and don't call `mainFrame.add(imageList.getPanel());` at all. A single control can be added only to one container.

Default layout of `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. When you add controls to `BorderLayout` without specifying layout constraint it places the control in `BorderLayout.CENTER`, effectively replacing whatever there was before.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor change to your code :)

instead of

```
scrollBar = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
```

use

```
scrollBar = new JScrollPane(imageView);
mainPanel.add(scrollBar);
```

and there is no need for

```
mainFrame.add(imageList.getScrollBar());
```

Comment: btw there is no need to set scrollBar static :)